# Where can I find itext.dtd?

Tags: itext, dtd

We were using http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/itext.dtd as our `DOCTYPE` in all our XML files which is actually a bad practice. We did not know it until our PDF generations failed since the site went down for some reason.

---

Any suggestions on where I could find the same dtd file?  We would need to download and locally host it. Tried Google search caches, but could not find the dtd file.

Comment: iText.NET was a fork of iText that died many, many years ago. The site was probably taken down by its owner. We at iText Software do not support forks of our library; we only support official versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've gone through my archives (you gave me quite some work) and I found a version of the itext.dtd

I've placed it here: http://lowagie.com/itext.dtd

Please download it and use it if you must. I've written this DTD more than 10 years ago, and frankly: it wasn't my best work. I have no idea why you'd still want use it.

**As soon as I see your acceptance of this message, I'll assume you've downloaded the DTD and I'll remove it form lowagie.com.**

Update: the file was removed from lowagie.com.

Comment: Got your message. Thanks for providing the DTD.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: Sir, if someone like me also have to get the same `dtd`, where should I go? I am generating bookmarks from `SimpleBookmark.ImportFromXML()` method. And I need to know the elements resides within `itext.dtd`, that `itextsharp` could understand. Could you please help me to get the same?

Comment: Your assumption that the itext.dtd file explains the Schema of the XML used for the SimpleBookmark class is wrong. The itext.dtd was used in very old iText versions to create PDF from XML. You need info about SimpleBookmark. This can be found in Chapter 7 of the book iText in Action - Second Edition (of which I'm the author).

Comment: Thank you sir, for your prompt reply. After a long search and reading some of your previous posts, the `SimpleBookmark.ImportFromXML()` method is clear to me from <http://wskidmore.com/2011/04/exporting-and-importing-pdf-bookmarks-itextsharp/>, but where I get info about the complete schema to be used with the method?

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: Sir, moreover, I have reviewed the `table 7.2` you mentioned for within `Chapter 7` of your book, but would be better have a the dtd/schema. Thanks again sir.

Comment: In all the years that SimpleBookmark exists, nobody ever asked for such a DTD or an XSD. We never made such a DTD or XSD. In other words: you're asking for something that doesn't exist. However, if you need one, please create one and contribute it to iText.

Comment: Ok sir, I will. Thanks again sir, for your kind co-operation.

Comment: The url to the dtd file returns a 404 now.