# Where can I find an iText xml reference?

Tags: xml, itext, razorpdf

I am evaluating the use of [RazorPDF](http://www.nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF) as our reporting solution. For some reason, I cannot find any iText XML reference, beside a [few](http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/examples/Chap0701.xml) [examples](https://gist.github.com/RazorAnt/3998480). There are plenty of example for the Java or C# API, but nothing regarding the XML itself.

Does such reference exists or do I have to figure it our from the examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read [Where can I find itext.dtd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975648/where-can-i-find-itext-dtd)

I'm the original developer of iText and I'm also the one who once upon a time, long ago, wrote the DTD for the iText XML files. That was even before XSD existed, so it's a really long time ago!

Support for this DTD has been removed from iText (I believe that was about when my first book was released in 2006) in favor of other ways to convert XML to PDF. It's very surprising to see that obsolete XML appear in something called RazorPDF.

In any case: I'm the CEO of the iText group, responsible for iText and iTextSharp, and I don't know anything about RazorPDF. I'm pretty sure RazorPDF uses a mighty old version of iText and my answer to this question explains why it shouldn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially

Comment: Guess that rules out RazorPDF, since finding support will be extremely hard. Thank you for this expert advice. I should warn the RazorPDF creator to get his opinion.

Comment: According to the source they're using iTextSharp 4.1.2

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, that's the C# port of iText 2.1.2. It dates from May 2008. Knowing how many bugs have been fixed since that date, it's very frustrating to find out people are still using it.

Comment: Yes it is old but is also the last (close to really) free versions of iTextSharp.

Comment: Could REALLY use some help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051773/razorpdf-itextsharp-open-anchor-with-target-blank

Comment: I get access denied on the Lowagie link

Comment: @Chad I've had to search my old archives, but I found an old version of the itext.dtd. I've put it here: http://itextpdf.org/documents/itext.dtd You shouldn't use it, though. You'll never pass due diligence if you use a version of iText that old. Let me know when you got it and I'll remove it.

Comment: Does it mean that the usage of XML and XHTML equivalents generate identical PDF?