# Open <anchor> with target="_blank"?

Tags: razorpdf

I am using RazorPdf to generate a .pdf document from one of my controller actions.  All works well, except that in my generated .pdf, I have an embedded anchor that opens yet another .pdf, that resides on the web site.

Currently, if the user clicks the anchor, the referenced .pdf opens *in the same browser window*.  **I don't want this behavior**.  I want anchor to open in a new browser tab (e.g. target="_blank"), but can't see any way to accomplish this.  Here's my anchor in my view:

```
<!-- Note: target="_blank" does not work //-->
<anchor target="_blank" font="underline" name="top" reference="http://www.example.com/Downloads/Attachment.pdf">Click Here</anchor>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some jquery function and call it on the click of the anchor tag

jquery function something like

$("#OpenAttachment").click(function (e) {

```
        var actionUrl = '/Downloads/Attachment.pdf';
        window.open(actionUrl, '', 'width=1000,height=800');
    });
```

This will open a new browser window. Hope this helps :)