# Applying style to div having a class name iTextSharp

Tags: itext

i have defined my html string as:

```
            string html = @"
                <html><body>    
                    <div class='class1'>My Text</div>    
                    </body></html>   
                    ";
```

To apply style, I am doing this

```
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();

            style.LoadTagStyle("class1", HtmlTags.FACE , "PATH" + "CustomFont.ttf");
```

This does not work. However, using this applies the font:

```
       style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.FACE , "PATH"+"CustomFont.ttf");
```

How to specify style to a particular class? I am generating pdf using iTextSharp dll.

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using? Also, `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated for a very long time in favor of `XMLWorker`, have you tried that instead?

Comment: i'm using version 5.4

Comment: I switched to XMLWorker. But again the same issue, not able to get the custom fonts working. Any help, need it urgenlty!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a class that implements the `IFontProvider` instance. XMLWorker ships with a class that implements that already so you can just use the `XMLWorkerFontProvider` class and register your fonts through that. The second parameter to the `Register()` method is optional but I recommend that you use it to explicitly give your font an alias.

Once you have that you can use the long form of `ParseXHtml()` which takes streams for both the HTML and CSS. If you're loading either of these two from disk you should check the encodings.

The below code is a full working example tested against iTextSharp and XMLWorker 5.2.4. See the comments for further details.

```
//File to output
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

//Standard PDF setup, nothing special here
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {

            //Open our document for writing
            doc.Open();

            //Our basic HTML
            var html = @"<html><body><div class=""class1"">My Text</div></body></html>";

            //Fully qualified path to our font
            var myFont = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ALGER.TTF");

            //Register our font and give it an alias to reference in CSS
            var fontProv = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
            fontProv.Register(myFont, "AlgerianRegular");

            //Create our CSS
            var css = @".class1{font-family: AlgerianRegular; color: #f00; font-size: 60pt;}";

            //Create a stream to read our HTML
            using (var htmlMS = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html))) {
                //Create a stream to read our CSS
                using (var cssMS = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css))) {
                    //Get an instance of the generic XMLWorker
                    var xmlWorker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

                    //Parse our HTML using everything setup above
                    xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, doc, htmlMS, cssMS, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, fontProv);
                }
            }

            //Close and cleanup
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference: not that there are no single quotes around the font-family name. I you add them, the xmlworker will not work.

Comment: I just tried the above code with and without quotes around `AlgerianRegular` against version 5.5.2 and both produced the correct output.