# iText xml - Getting strange page breaks in Pdf with itextsharp

Tags: c#, xml, itext

In our application we have the strange behaviour that multiple page breaks are added in the converted pdf document. The problem occurs only if the the document fills multiple pages. I dont't have any idea why this is happening.

I have attached two files:
- The xml file with the itext xml code ([input.xml](http://212.243.102.118/DownloadLinks/SupportRequests/Stackoverflow/input.xml))
- The output pdf file where you see the odd result ([output.pdf](http://212.243.102.118/DownloadLinks/SupportRequests/Stackoverflow/output.pdf))

I am using iTextSharp version 3.1.5.0.
I would be very glad for any help. Thanks.

Comment: iTextSharp 3.1.5.0 dates from a very long time ago (even before we created tags in the SVN repository for iTextSharp). That version is no longer supported. You shouldn't expect an answer.

Comment: I know that this is a very old version. Also, I think iText Xml in general is not longer supported. However, we cannot replace our whole Pdf convert engine by now. Or does a current version of iTextSharp support iText xml?

Comment: XML Worker converts simple HTML to PDF: [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker). You're probably using the proprietary format I created in 2000. I abandoned it a long time ago. Your application must be very old. Maybe it's time to rewrite it, so that you're ready for new PDF standards such as ISO-32000-2, PDF/UA and so on.

Comment: I'm slightly confused to your actual problem. You have a document that you _know_ is supposed to fill multiple pages, and it does, right? I'm looking at a three-page PDF and your XML has a bunch of tables that would naturally require multiple tables. Am I missing something?

Comment: Further, to back Bruno's answer (the creator of iText), read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28768213/231316) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21679509/231316)

Comment: Look like there is an error in xml.  From : </row>+<row> To : </row>